# File content corrupted when writing to NFS share from windows

Tags: windows, nfs

We have an NFS share on an IBM zSeries which is mounted on windows and on AIX.
Files written from windows are unreadable on AIX and from AIX on windows. I've tried a number of single and multibyte encoding, with and without BOM with utf8.

Are there are parameters which affect transcoding either from the server or the client side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might simply be an `UTF-16LE` (Windows) vs `UTF-16BE` (AIX) vs `EBCDIC` (zSeries) incompatibility. Examine the files with a hexviewer (`od -tx1 _filename_` in AIX) to find out. (Good choice would be UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. NFS on AIX has an option to mount in binary, so the whole transfer path remains binary. 
This is not the standard option with all other shares on the AIX mounting as text and transcoding making the data usable on the zSeries. As this data is never used on the zSeries, but a pass through from Windows to AIX, the whole path is defined as binary and all good.